# run node in gvim :ReferenceError: range is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim

My system : xp + gvim+node.js
I have open gvim to edit a javascript sentence ,the file has no name yet.

```
 print(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

when i input

```
:w !node
```

I get the error outputs :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ( node ^<C:\DOCUME~1\sanya\LOCALS~1\Temp\VIi8C.tmp)    
print(sum(range(1, 10)));    
  ^    
ReferenceError: range is not defined    
at [stdin]:1:11    
at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)    
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)    
at evalScript (node.js:532:25)    
at ReadStream.<anonymous> (node.js:154:11)    
at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)    
at _stream_readable.js:920:16    
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)    
shell returned 8    
Hit any key to close this window...
```

How can i fix the error?

when i change the `print(sum(range(1, 10)));` into `print("hallo world");` in gvim ,and input `w ! node`,i got the same output?

why in javasript window in  eloquentjavascript.net/chapter1.html ,i can get right answer?

[image]

Comment: What does vim have to do with the fact that your node program has a bug?  Also, where are "sum" and "range" defined?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't Python?

Comment: i know what is  wrong ,i am reading http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter1.html,it is not python surely .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You must define the "range", "sum", and "print" functions.

Once you do that your JavaScript code will be executable by the node interpreter.

Also, the use of gvim is irrelevant here.  Running that code from the command line will have the same results.